# ASP.NET Core Razor page model lose information after post

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a model, that I use in my **Razor page**, I can access it's properties and if I assign some value to them, I can access it in my Post method, but not the embedded object I have.

Why my Address is NULL?

**My model:**

```
 public class AddressModel
 {
    public string Street{get;set;}
    // More props...
 }

 public class PersonModel
 {
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public int Age{get;set;}
    public AddressModel Address {get;set;}
 }
```

**Razor page with codebehind page:**

***cshtml.cs***

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
 {
    [BindProperty]
    public PersonModel Person{get;set;}

    public IActionResult OnGet() { return Page(); }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        // Person.Name is filled and have the string I typed
        // Person.Age is filled and have the value I typed
        // but Person.Address is  NULL. Why?
    }
 }
```

***cshtml:***

```
@page
@model CreateModel

 <form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Person.Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Person.Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Person.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Person.Age" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Person.Age" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Person.Age" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    // ...
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Person.Address.Street" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Person.Address.Street" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Address.Prop3.Street" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
// ...
</form>
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue, I took your exact code and created new page in ASP.NET Core 3.0 project and Person.Address is of type AddressModel and Street property has value from the form. Have you tried with fresh template with this exact code and nothing extra added?

Comment: I haven't try it in a fresh project. btw. I use ASP.NET Core 2.2

Comment: Omg.... sorry, I found the bug. In the real app there are about 30 inputs inside 20 div tags and the inputs of Address was outside my form tag... Sorry again, I was thinking on this issue for 2 days. omg.